# Java IO "NaN" issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a file named **Numbers.txt** with the following content:

```
8.5

83.45, 90.2

120.00, 11.05

190.00
```

I have written code that uses the contents of the file to compute the sum and average of the numbers in the file however when I run the code, for the average the result is "NaN"

CODE:

```
package lab13;

import java.util.Scanner; 

import java.io.*;

public class problem1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {   

        double sum = 0;     
        int count = 0;
        double num,total = 0;
        double average = total/count;


        File file = new File("Numbers.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);


        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
            double number = scan.nextDouble();

            sum = sum + number;
        }  

        while (scan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            num = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(num);
            count++;
            total += num;

        }

        scan.close();

        System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in " +
                "Numbers.txt is " + sum );       

        System.out.println("The average of the numbers in " +
                "Numbers.txt is " + average );  


    }
}
```

Output:

The sum of the numbers in Numbers.txt is 503.2

The average of the numbers in Numbers.txt is NaN

Comment: `double average = total/count;` - You're dividing `0` by `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do

```
double average = total/count;
```

**after** you have the values for `total` and `count`

**But** also note that

when `while (scan.hasNext())` stream is exhausted then `while (scan.hasNextDouble())` will also be exhausted

This can be overcome but just looping once